# iText cannot read text from PDF if using True Type 3 font

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

Does anyone why this is occurring, or how to correct this problem? I am currently using iTextSharp to read in a PDF, and just get the text from the page as a string by using

```
iTextExtractionStrategy = pdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

pdfText = iTextExtractionStrategy.GetResultantText();
```

Does anyone know why the reading is null, and on other PDF's it is fine?

Comment: Is this only possible in OCR, and in that, not possible with iText? I would assume this would not be an issue.

Comment: Type 3 fonts are *user defined fonts*. For instance: character 'a' corresponds with a lamp, character 'P' corresponds with the symbol representing *The Artist Formerly Known As Prince*, character 'z' corresponds with the logo of Winzip. In short: Type 3 fonts are used to allow users to introduce custom glyphs that may or may not correspond with actual letters from the alphabet. Hence it should be no surprise that you can't extract meaningful text when encountering snippets of Type 3 font "text".