# iTextSharp GetTextFromPage does not work with postscript font?

Tags: itext

I had iTextSharp version 5.5 in the .net project in visual studio 2005 and tried to retrieve some text from a PDF file but it does not work.

The program work with some other PDFs.

And in the end I found it has been caused by the postscript font, the iTextSharp does not work. However very old version iTextSharp like version 2, it can work with postscript font.

If I change the font to true type font, both iTextSharp versions are working.
My code is very simple, like below

```
Dim reader As PdfReader
reader = New PdfReader(pdf) 
Dim textExtract As String = String.Empty 
textExtract = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1)
```

*textExtract* got a empty new line without "Hello World" text from the PDF document.

You may download the PDF file from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PvEMuJQOSyUEJ6SVFkX3NHQlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your `postscript font` is a type 3 font without the information required for mapping the character codes to Unicode. Thus, text extraction can only guess. The correct guess is to assume ASCII encoding, but the application can only guess.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922730/itext-cannot-read-text-from-pdf-if-using-true-type-3-font

Comment: Thanks, mkl and Bruno. Is there anyyway I can deal with this issue. I had the itextsharp source code but seems it is not easy work to understand and modify the code to work for my particular job.

Comment: *I had the itextsharp source code but seems it is not easy work to understand and modify the code to work for my particular job.* - in the Java code in `CMapAwareDocumentFont.decodeSingleCID(byte[], int, int)` you might want to try and return something along the lines of `String.valueOf((char)bytes[offset])` where it returns `""`; in iTextSharp a similar solution might be worth a try for you. BTW, the type 3 font you are using actually is quite disgusting: Each character is described by an inline image bitmap!

Comment: thanks, mkl. The pdf document is created from the third party tools. And I will try according your suggestion.

Comment: according to MKL's suggestion, I modified iTextSharp code in DecodeSingleCID and added "else" of "if (toUnicodeCmap != null)", so the code will "return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, offset, len);" in the "else"  block. I can get the expacted text now. Thanks MKL and Bruno